# How to deal with large number inside of for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, infinite-loop

I am working on hacker rank problem.
Repeated String
[1] : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem

```
function main() {
    var s = readLine();
    var n = parseInt(readLine());
    var rep = 0;
    var repArray = []

//calculate each case 

  while(repArray.length < n){
      for(let j = 0; j < s.length; j++){
           if(repArray.length > n){
              break;
         }
          repArray.push(s[j])
      }
  }

  for(let a = 0; a < repArray.length; a++){
     if(repArray[a] === 'a'){
          rep++
      } 
  }
  console.log(rep)
}
```

I am receiving an error for the input 
a
1000000000000

the output of my code is 
<--- Last few GCs --->

```
1836 ms: Mark-sweep 597.4 (605.3) -> 359.7 (368.6) MB, 101.7 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
1938 ms: Mark-sweep 359.7 (368.6) -> 359.7 (368.6) MB, 102.3 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
2040 ms: Mark-sweep 359.7 (368.6) -> 359.7 (367.6) MB, 101.6 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
2142 ms: Mark-sweep 359.7 (367.6) -> 359.7 (367.6) MB, 101.7 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
```

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

> Security context: 0x10178c2cfb51 
>       2: main [/run-N6KBYU8cQzCneXKH0Tbm/solution.js:~30] [pc=0x2859725aec0] (this=0x10178c2e6119 )
>       3: /* anonymous */ [/run-N6KBYU8cQzCneXKH0Tbm/solution.js:21] [pc=0x2859725717e] (this=0x2af8d3a77e81 )
>       4: emitNone(aka emitNone) [events.js:91] [pc=0x28597256c33] (this=0x10178c204381 ,handler=0x2af8d3a78049 ,is...

the error of this code is

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory  1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/nodejs-binary/bin/node] 
>   2: 0x1098b2c [/usr/local/nodejs-binary/bin/node]  3:
>   v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*)
>   [/usr/local/nodejs-binary/bin/node]  4:
>   v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool)
>   [/usr/local/nodejs-binary/bin/node]  5:
>   v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int)
>   [/usr/local/nodejs-binary/bin/node]  6: 0xc4553f
>   [/usr/local/nodejs-binary/bin/node]  7:
>   v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, v8::internal::Object**,
>   v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/nodejs-binary/bin/node]  8:
>   0x285971079a7

Comment: Hint: This problem can be solved without actually generating and traversing the string.

Comment: That challenge looks like C, is the challenge converting C to JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem to find an efficient algorithm. You can't use brute force to solve these kinds of problems.

`n` is intentionally set to a high value so that you don't try to brute force. `10^12` is `1 Trillion`, even if you could run each iteration of your loop in `one nano second` it would take `1000 seconds`, which is long given that it's impossible to run each iteration in `one nano second`.

Problem that you're facing is because of the `Space complexity`, you're trying to store `(n=10^12)` (Max value) characters in memory. If each character takes `1 byte` then the size of memory that we need is

```
10^12 bytes = 1000 Giga bytes = 1 Terra byte
```

I'm sure that your program won't be given that memory. Given there must other  people trying to solve this problem at the same time. `Hackerrank` can't give this much resource to all of them.

Problem never intended for you to store this value in memory. Intention is for you to find a clever way of solving it without needing to store all the values.

Now clever way is that you can count how many `a`s are in `s`. Now all you have to do is find out how many strings `s` you can repeat if you have only `n` characters.

Spoiler below (click/hover to view the answer):

> That can be caculated by `Math.floor(n / s.length)`. Now there may be some remaining string at the end which has length `n % s.length`. So the solution would be `count = Math.floor(n / s.length) * CountAsIn(s) + CountAsIn(s.substring(n % s.length))`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getAOcc (s) {
  return s.match(/a/g)?.length || 0;
}

function repeatedString(s, n) {
  // Write your code here
  let stringLength = s.length;
  let aOcc = 0;
  const actualAOcc = getAOcc(s);
  
  if (!actualAOcc) return 0;
  
  const totalRep = Math.floor(n / stringLength);
  
  aOcc = actualAOcc * totalRep;
  
  const modS = n % stringLength
  if (modS > 0) {
      aOcc += getAOcc(s.substring(0, modS));
  }
  
  return aOcc;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).